# MVC3 @Model becomes null in layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, model, null

So I have something odd happening in a MVC3 layout I created.  It's strongly typed to BaseVM.  Every View model inherits from BaseVM.  When I debug and step through the code and it it steps through my layout, the BaseVM model is not null and it calls a method to get the current year for the copyright in the footer.  But as soon as I step to the bottom of the layout, it throws an exception back up where I was calling the property to get the year and suddenly the Model is null.  Now this doesn't cause the application to show an error screen or message, but this exception gets logged every time the page is loaded.  Here's a code sample:

```
public class BaseVM
{
    public string CurrentYear
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();
        }
    }

    public BaseVM()
    {
    }
}

public class PrelaunchReserveVM : BaseVM
{
    public PrelaunchDTO Prelaunch { get; set; }

    public PrelaunchReserveVM()
        : this(new PrelaunchDTO()) { }

    public PrelaunchReserveVM(PrelaunchDTO prelaunch)
        : base()
    {
        this.Prelaunch = prelaunch;
    }
}
```

The action in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Reserve()
{
    return View("Reserve", new PrelaunchReserveVM(new PrelaunchDTO()));
}
```

The layout:

```
@model StickyThink.Models.VM.BaseVM
```

...

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main" role="main" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div id="FooterPageContainer" class="center">
        Copyright &copy @Model.CurrentYear ...  All rights reserved.
    </div>
</footer>
<!-- END: Add your site or application content here -->
@Html.Partial("_Scripts")
@RenderSection("scripts", false);
```

So it steps into @Model.CurrentYear and model is not null.  Then it steps down to @RenderSection (to render some scripts from the view) and then an exception is thrown and @Model is null.  Thoughts?

Comment: What does your `RenderSection` looks like?

Comment: What model inside a _Layout? This doesn't make sense. The model is specific for each view whereas the Layout is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass Model as the 2nd parameter in `@Html.Partial("_Scripts", Model)`.

Comment: Not if it is being used as an include.

Comment: How so? I'm not sure I'm familiar with "a Model being used as an include". It might be something that I am, but aren't familiar with the term.

Comment: Partial being used like an include.  Does not need model if model not used.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with the Partial or RenderSection.  Those exist to keep my scripts in one tidy place and RenderSection exists so that my jQuery will function correctly seeing as how I include my scripts at the bottom of the page.  I did try your suggestion and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to take a wild guess, I think there is a problem with the content of the _Scripts partial.  Maybe it needs the model @krillgar, but my guess onn that would be no.  I would suggest moving the _Scripts partial to NOT be a partial and reference the scripts in the header like normal.  I suspect that this exception will then shows its face earlier and help you find the problem, and the reason the Model becomes null is becuase of the type of exception.  So if you move the _Scripts partial and have null earlier, you know this is the place to look.

Comment: I moved my _Scripts partial to the top along with the RenderSection.  Stepping through it gets to the @Model.CurrentYear and shows that it has a year, then right after, at the end of the document it throws a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception.  It doesn't make any sense.  It's possible it could have something to do with one my NuGet packages.  I'm going to create a new project and try to replicate the issue. :-)